# Google Analytics - Client requested Event Tags and provided script. How do I implement it?

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

and thank you in advance for any guidance! 
I have created a basic HTML/CSS website for a friends business but now someone from their team has requested this script is added to their site to track external link clicks.

```
<script> 
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'uaevent', 
'ecommerce': 'undefined',
'eventCategory': 'outbound links',
'eventAction': 'select::url',
'eventLabel': '([link name] | [target-url])' 
}); 
</script>
```

My knowledge of analytics scripts is very limited and I have never done this before.

They have requested this script "fires off" for the links on their site.
(links below)

```
<a href="https://saloncentric.secure.force.com/candidateportal/FCMS__CMSLayout? 
jobSite=All%20Brands&p=Candidate&page=JobListPage" target="_blank"><button 
class="bannerbutton">VIEW ALL BRAND OPPORTUNITIES</button></a>
```

and this one

```
<a href="https://saloncentric.secure.force.com/candidateportal/FCMS__CMSLayout? 
jobSite=All%20Brands&p=Candidate&page=JobListPage" target="_blank"><div 
class="calltoactionfooter">
<button class="footerbutton">CLICK HERE TO VIEW ALL BRAND OPPORTUNITIES</button>
    </div> </a>
```

I have tried adding the "link name" (view all brand..) and "target-url" (external link) to the script and added it to the head but I do not believe that is correct. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if the team is going to be utilizing Google Tag Manager to manage tags? If they are, you'll need some additional snippets. One needs to be placed at the top of the opening head tag and the other at the top of the opening body tag. Once those are placed, they should be able to manage all of the events on their end through GTM.

Comment: Yes, they will be using Google Tag Manager. I have already added in the GTM code in the head and just below the body. Now they want to track the events (external link clicks)

Comment: Perfect! So now that you've done all of the initial setup, they would just need to create a GA Event with a just links trigger. They would set it up to check validation and enable the trigger when the page URL matches RegEx ".*". The trigger would then be setup to fire on link clicks where the click URL does not match what ever the domain is. The majority of the work should be done through GTM.

Comment: First off, thank you so much for responding, I really appreciate it. They insist that it is something I need to set up in the code. They even provided me with this selection of links they want to see trigged, and the code to set it up.

https://imgur.com/hOActvB

Comment: If you have setup the GTM on the website and it is working fine that's your job done. My opinion is that link tracking should be implemented through GTM (with exceptions). I reckon they insist you setup something because they prefer you do the work instead of them.

Comment: I completely agree. I told them I wasnt 100% sure how to set this up for them and they were so specific I mentioned if someone from their team could do it and they said they expect us (the web designer) to do it. I'll mention this to them again and see how it goes. Thank you so much for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ihavenoidea, this should be done through GTM, but you can also do it in your website like this:

```
<script> 

const bannerButtonClick = () => {
  const url = "https://saloncentric.secure.force.com/candidateportal/FCMS__CMSLayout?jobSite=All%20Brands&p=Candidate&page=JobListPage";

  dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'uaevent', 
    'ecommerce': 'undefined',
    'eventCategory': 'outbound links',
    'eventAction': url,
    'eventLabel': 'bannerButton' 
  });

  window.location.href = url;
}

</script>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="bannerButtonClick()" target="_blank"><button 
class="bannerbutton">VIEW ALL BRAND OPPORTUNITIES</button></a>
```

So we create a function bannerButtonClick and when the link is clicked instead of redirecting to href we execute a javascript function that first sends data to dataLayer and then redirects to the URL.

As you have multiple links you will need multiple functions or one that is more clever but the same logic will apply.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Im 100% sure this is what they were asking for but like you mentioned it should be done on their end through GTM. Would I be able to copy/paste this into the head and it should start working for them?

Comment: Yes you need to put the JavaScript into head and edit the link HTML code and it will start working.